# vb.net process.start replaces clipboard content

Tags: vb.net, clipboard, process.start

When I execute a program (any program) using Process.Start (for example Process.Start("explorer.exe", "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")), the contents of my Windows 10 clipboard is deleted and replaced by the text property of the object that called explorer.exe. Can anyone explain why Process.Start overwrites the clipboard and how I can prevent that? Any answers would be gratefully received. -- P

Comment: It would help us to help you, if you could post the code you have that will reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Not an answer, I can't explain it, but what exactly are you trying to do here? Why not just Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe") and not use the 2nd param forgoing the problem of using the 2nd param?

Comment: @Hursey, I haven't tested to confirm but I think that that code opens a File Explorer window and selects the specified file, rather than running the specified file.